# Two errors: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' and syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, 17.10, c++, syntax

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

My current Ubuntu version is 17.10

I saved the above C++ program on my external hard disk and opened it with Sublime Text 2. The code compiles successfully but when I run it I get these two errors:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

The problem goes away if I save it and run it on anywhere other than my hard disk.

What's happening here?

Comment: What command are you using to run it?

Comment: +1 sounds like you're trying to run the `.cpp` file - instead of running the executable *produced by* compiling and linking the `.cpp` file

Comment: @wjandrea CTRL+B for compiling and CTRL+SHIFT+B to run it.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not doing anything different from other programs other than saving it on my hard disk. When I save the main .cpp file on say the Desktop, everything works fine.

Comment: If you compile and run it manually, do you get the same error?

Comment: @wjandrea Actually, I don't. When I compile and run it using the command line it compiles successfully and I get the correct output, no errors here. Looks like the problem is with Sublime Text 2. In fact  even CodeBlocks doesn't give this error.

Comment: @CodeCraft yep, looks like a bug